# JNI ByteBuffer put bytes

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, bytebuffer, nosuchmethoderror

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_directshowcamera_dsInterface_grab_1frame_1stream(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint streamid, jobject barray)
{
    jclass bbclass = env->FindClass( "java/nio/ByteBuffer" );
    jmethodID putMethod = env->GetMethodID(bbclass, "put", "(I, B)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer");
    unsigned char *buffer = stream_buffer( streamid );

    if( !stream_image_ready( streamid ) ) return (jboolean)0;

    for(int i=0; i < stream_device_size( streamid ); i++ ) {
        env->CallByteMethod( barray, putMethod, i, (jbyte)buffer[i] );
    }

    return (jboolean)1;
}
```

So, I have a byte buffer, and in Java I've allocated the appropriate size, and noticed it's possible to to ByteBuffer.put( index, byte ), so I tried to get the method, but when I do in Java, I get the following runtime exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: put

Any ideas what I've done wrong?  I don't know JNI that well, and have mostly been re-working examples I've found off the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method signature `(I, B)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer` is wrong. There is no `,` between arguments in method signatures and classes are `L<class>;` (you forgot the `;`).

So the correct signature is: `(IB)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;`

Then the code should work.

Comment: @OzBarry Did I forget to answer a part of your question or why haven't you selected an answer yet?

Comment: Sorry about that - I tried to, but it said that I had to wait 2 minutes, and I got caught up in some other things.  No worries, I got your back!

Comment: @OzBarry Don't try to figure out these Java method signature stings yourself. javap -s does it for you, flawlessly.

Comment: Great answer, it took me some time before I realised that only classes are delimited by ; and primitive types are not.